# What is "homologous map"?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, game-theory

I'm reading a paper of Hillas about stability of game, and I found that the author uses a term "homologous" between continuous maps. I've never heard about such term before, and I can't find the definition in wikipedia. It seems that "homologous" is coarser than "homotopic", in the sense that if two continuous maps are homotopic then they are homologous. Also, the map is not homologous to a constant map if its graph has holes in it. It seems that this means the graph of the map is not null-homotopic.

I can only find a definition of "homologous" between two paths, not two maps. 
Could you give a formal definition of the term "homologous"? Thanks in advance.

Edit : Here is a [link](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.324.3076&rep=rep1&type=pdf) to the paper.

Comment: @EricWofsey I added a link. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is just an error on the part of the author (though it is possible that this terminology is standard in game theory; I haven't investigated thoroughly).  When they refer to a map being "homologous to a trivial map", what they actually mean is just that the induced map on homology is zero (compare to the definition at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens-stable_equilibrium#Definition_of_a_Stable_Set, for instance, though that one uses cohomology instead of homology).

Comment: I think this is right. Thanks! I have one more question, what do you think the sentence "the projection map $proj_{\epsilon}:(S_{\epsilon}, \partial S_{\epsilon})\to (P_{\epsilon}, \partial P_{\epsilon})$ is not homotopic to a map to $\partial P_{\epsilon}$" means? I cannot understand what "a map to $\partial P_{\epsilon}$" is... This is in the definition 2 in page 5.

Comment: A map to $\partial P_\epsilon$ is just a map whose image is contained in $\partial P_\epsilon$.  We have a map $S_\epsilon\to P_\epsilon$, and we're asking whether there is a homotopy from it to a map which only takes values in the subset $\partial P_\epsilon$ of $P_\epsilon$.

Comment: I think that in your phrase "the induced map on homology is nonzero", the intention is "zero" instead of "nonzero".

Comment: @LeeMosher: Thanks, I've fixed that.

Comment: I don't think it's an error.  That's exactly the term and the meaning I used when I did algebraic topology.